# How much electricity a human can conduct?

Tags: current

I have watched video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRf9MqqkMDM)  when a man exhibits  conductivity through his body. But how much current can a human conducts safely?   Is there any trick?

I have heard from a man who said that " **I'd like to see him connect one wire to his left foot and the other to his right arm. It'll make current pass through his heart. Just a thousandth of an amp passing through any human being's heart can kill them**.﻿"

How true is that?

Comment: Not as true as if you go from right foot to left arm.

Answer (score 0):

30 mA is enough to kill with skin contact, touching a live wire, for example.

Avoid the man who said that.

Comment: How about the video?

Answer (score 0):

There probably is a trick. For this video they changed the frequency of the AC voltage to some value for the heart being unsusceptible to ventricular fibrillation. For 100 kHz or greater this is proven. With even higher frequencies the current will only flow on the surface of the body.

Comment: Do you *know* that there's a frequency for which the heart is  unsusceptible to ventricular fibrillation?  If not, I suggest deleting the answer.

Comment: 100 kHz and above are used in surgery. See electrocautery and electrosurgery.